# From a controller get a view with a new route value in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble figuring out how to, from the controller, get a view with a route value. i.e. I want to save the values from an edit page and then re-open the edit page with a new specific id value.

I have tried `Return View(myNewId)` but that for some reason becomes a post. I have tried `Return RedirectToAction(myNewId)` but that doesn't seem to pass the new value but passes the old value.

Comment: Have you tried `RedirectToAction(actionName: "Edit", routeValues: new { id = myNewId })`? Perhaps show us what you tried.

Comment: The two things I tried are in the second paragraph above. I tried with the format you showed and it does work now.